# Use TVP name in SET and JOIN clauses

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, table-valued-parameters

I have a requirement in SQL Server 2008 R2 to pass in many rows for an update to many rows. I decided to try a Table Valued Parameter to accomplish this. First - I created the type on the server.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[crm_question_idx_type] AS TABLE(
    [survey_question_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [row_index] [int] NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (survey_question_id)
)
GO
```

This went fine but the problem arose when attempting to create the Stored Procedure to use the new type. The code for creating the new procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.crm_question_index_update
(
@question_idx dbo.crm_question_idx_type READONLY
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE crm_survey_question 
SET crm_survey_question.row_index = @question_idx.row_index
FROM crm_survey_question 
INNER JOIN @question_idx 
    ON crm_survey_question.survey_question_id =  @question_idx.survey_question_id
```

When I attempt to compile this on the server I get the following error:

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure crm_question_index_update, Line 10
>   
> Must declare the scalar variable "@question_idx".

Now in my code `@question_idx` is an input parameter of type `dbo.crm_question_idx` so I can't understand why this error is popping up.

Comment: Who ever edited this is partially wrong. That error message was cut and pasted from SQL Management Studio "as is" on the compile attempt.

Comment: The only edit I can see was one that improved the *formatting* of the question whilst leaving the text intact. Do you have a specific issue with what's been done with it?

Comment: When I was viewing the edits - the error message that I pasted in had been changed - it now looks like it is back to the original text.

Comment: No, all I did was change the formatting of that error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases are your friend. In this case not only do they simplify the amount of code, but they are required when referencing table variables or TVPs.

```
UPDATE c
  SET c.row_index = q.row_index
  FROM dbo.crm_survey_question AS c
  INNER JOIN @question_idx AS q
  ON c.survey_question_id = q.survey_question_id;
```

Comment: That worked - will mark as answer as soon as the 11 minute timer is up :) - Thanks so much.